# Como buscar uma string que varia de posicao

Tags: sql, postgresql

Veja abaixo dois resultados retornados de uma tabela onde armazeno plano de execucao de consultas sqls. Eu utilizo o POSTGRESQL
Eu necessito capturar somente a string cost=399301.55 do resultado abaixo. A palavra custo sempre vem no inicio, mas nem sempre vem na 
mesma posicao, por isso nao da para fazer simplesmente substring (...). 
Eu acho que deve-se encontrar a posicao inicial e final toda vez, para ser possive extrair somente o valor de custo.
Se alguem puder me ajudar, o resultado esperado para  o exemplo abaixo eh:

### select (.... )

cost=399301

----------------- cadeia de string de exemplo -----------------------

```
"Sort  (cost=399301.55..399301.57 rows=6 width=36)"
"  Sort Key: l_returnflag, l_linestatus"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=399301.21..399301.48 rows=6 width=36)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on h_lineitem  (cost=0.00..250095.98 rows=5968209 width=36)"
"              Filter: (l_shipdate <= (to_date('1998/12/01'::text, 'YYYY/MM/DD'::text) - '10 days'::interval day))"
```

---------------- outra cadeia de string de exemplo --------------------

```
"Aggregate  (cost=7922058.70..7922058.71 rows=1 width=16)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1899763.92..7922058.69 rows=1 width=16)"
"        Hash Cond: (h_lineitem.l_partkey = h_part.p_partkey)"
"        Join Filter: (((h_part.p_brand = 'Brand#13'::bpchar) AND (h_part.p_container = ANY ('{"SM CASE","SM BOX","SM PACK","SM PKG"}'::bpchar[])) AND (h_lineitem.l_quantity >= 4::double precision) AND (h_lineitem.l_quantity <= 14::double precision) AND (h_ (...)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on h_lineitem  (cost=0.00..235156.84 rows=211094 width=32)"
"              Filter: ((l_shipmode = ANY ('{AIR,"AIR REG"}'::bpchar[])) AND (l_shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON'::bpchar))"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=1183158.46..1183158.46 rows=35278997 width=33)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on h_part  (cost=0.00..1183158.46 rows=35278997 width=33)"
"                    Filter: (p_size >= 1)"
```

Comment: Use combinações de functions como POSITION e SUBSTRING , eu pensaria em uma função de usuário para tratar isto    , o segundo passo e rever , se possível , o modelo      https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.ht ml

Comment: Esqueça o comentário do modelo ....

Comment: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/171-Explain-Plans-PostgreSQL-9.0-Text,-JSON,-XML,-YAML-Part-1-You-Choose.html

Comment: Ola Mota, eu estava pensando em fazer uma funcao mesmo primeiro pegando a posicao do cost= e o limite superior.  E apos delimitar o inicio e fim pegar o valor utilizando substring (  from for) ..SELECT POSITION ('..' IN 'Aggregate  (cost=27726324.40..27726324.41 Rows = '); 
SELECT POSITION ('Rows' IN 'Aggregate.. Mas me ocorreu de utilizar expressao regular, esta quase certa, somente estou pegando o valor antes dos .. (dois pontos) e na verdade queria pegar o valor apos os .. (dois pontos) veja... select substring('Aggregate  (cost=27726324.40..27726324.41 Rows =' from '\[0-9]+.?[0-9]{2}') ;

Comment: Não conheço PostgreeSQL mas será que esta tabela ou outra não já tem dados separados ?

Comment: No Oracle  eu sei que tem uma tabela chamada PlanTable que tem as informacoes divididas por campo, mas no postgresql conheco uma extensao que faz isso pg_stats_plan, mas eu nao posso utilizar ela por motivos de projeto e versao. Infelizmente tenho que obter dessa forma.

Answer (score -1):

Eu quase consegui resolver o problema com Expressao regular. Veja abaixo o que fiz:

```
select substring('Aggregate (cost=27726324.40..27726324.41 Rows' from '[.][0-9]+.?[0-9]{2}');
```

> ### -------- RESULTADO .27726324.41

Veja que apareceu um ponto inicialmente, e gostaria de retirar o mesmo. Alguem tem alguma dica de como fazer para retirar o ponto inicial ? O que preciso eh do numero apos os dois pontos consecutivos ".."

Comment: Eu consegui modificar a ER e consegui retirar o ponto inicial (.27726324.41), com a seguinte solucao:  select substring('Aggregate (cost=27726324.40..27726324.41 Rows' from '[.]Y*([0-9]+.?[0-9]{2})')        RESULT       27726324.41